# What does this line of code related to __str__(self) mean?

Tags: python, class, object

Help me understand what `object` means in this line: `s = '    ' + object.__str__(obj)`. I have not seen `object` referred to anywhere in the code, is it a special keyword? What does it mean in this context?

The link to the full code: http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/code/GoodKangaroo.py

I can't wrap my head around that one line

```py
def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representaion of this Kangaroo.
        """
        t = [ self.name + ' has pouch contents:' ]
        for obj in self.pouch_contents:
            s = '    ' + object.__str__(obj)
            t.append(s)
        return '\n'.join(t)
```

Comment: That's silly. Correct way of doing it would be `s = '    ' + str(obj)`.

Comment: @Marco. Silly, probably, but it does serve a purpose

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: That’s not infinite recursion unless there’s a physically improbable arrangement of kangaroos. But it does avoid recursion more generally :)

Comment: Not if `obj` defines its own `__str__` method and you intended to avoid it by specifically calling the base from `object`

Comment: @Ry- you are right, I was looking for a motivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line of code is a way of converting `obj` into a string, by calling the default `__str__` method of **the base type `object`**, which generates a string containing the class name and the address of the instance in memory, like for example `<Kangaroo instance at 0xAABBCC>`.

Normally, one would use `str(obj)`, but in this case, if `obj` is another `Kangaroo`, then the same `__str__()` method defined in `Kangaroo` would be called recursively, thus causing something like this to be generated:

```
foo = Kangaroo('foo')
bar = Kangaroo('bar')
baz = Kangaroo('baz')

baz.put_in_pouch(1)
bar.put_in_pouch(baz)
foo.put_in_pouch(bar)

# Result of print str(foo)

foo has pouch contents:
    bar has pouch contents:
    baz has pouch contents:
    1
```

Using `object.__str__()` instead, avoids calling the method recursively and gives:

```
# Result of print str(foo)

foo has pouch contents:
    <__main__.Kangaroo instance at 0x7fc3a864d128>
```

Answer (score 1):

`object` refers to the builtin base class, which is an object. typing `object` into the Python REPL provides this...

```
>>> object
<class 'object'>
```

It is the base class included with the standard scope in python.

---

Here, this is the [only reference I can actually find in the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-object)

> **object**
>
> Any data with state (attributes or value) and defined behavior (methods). Also the ultimate base class of any new-style class.

---

[I FOUND IT!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object)

> class **object**
> Return a new featureless *object*. *object* is a base for
> all classes. It has the methods that are common to all instances of
> Python classes. This function does not accept any arguments.

Comment: as a follow-up, I tried to find some python docs specifying exactly this. anyone else have any luck?

Comment: See my answer for more details but the behavior when called this way is given in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__repr__

Answer (score 0):

[`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object) is python's base class.

In this case the code is calling [`object.__str__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__) which will use `object`'s method of turning `obj` into a string. This will call [`object.__repr__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__repr__) which will print out the "official" representation of the object.

For strings this will be `'[string contents]'` (with `[string contents]` replaced with the actual contents of the string) and for generic objects this will be `<[object name] at [address]>` (again with `[object name]` and `[address]` replaced with the object's actual name and address).

Note: `object.__str__(obj)` and `str(obj)` will return different results since `object.__str__(obj)` will eventually call `repr(obj)`.